# Problems creating list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, append, subset, nested-lists

I have been trying to create a list of lists in R. I start by creating a list of lists of prespecified length. I then iterate through a matrix using a for loop to fill the lists.

The problem is that I seem to be getting lists of lists of lists etc.

My code:

```
potential_dups <- rep(list(list()), 10)
nearest10 <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10)

for (i in 1:length(nearest10[ , 1])) {
  for (j in 1:10) {
    if (nearest10[i, j] < 0.35 && nearest10[i, j] > 0) {
      potential_dups[[i]] <- append(potential_dups[[i]], nearest10[i, j])
    }
  } 
}
```

Why is this happening? How can I create a lists of this format?

```
[[1]]
[1] "Element 1A"
[[1]]
[2] "Element 1B"
[[1]]
[3] "Element 1C"

[[2]]
[1] "Element 2A"
[[2]]
[2] "Element 2B"
```

Additionally, I am ending up with empty list that are displayed for example as:
    [[3]]
    list()
There first elements are NULL. I would additionally like to write script that subsets out only the non-empty lists from this data structure.

Comment: Why do you use `append`?

Comment: @Roland I saw it in a previous stackoverflow  example. I've tried taking it out and using c, but its still not working.

Comment: Please make you code reproducible by adding the output of `dput(nearest10_scores)`.

Comment: @Roland ok I borrowed code from user2568961 to make mine reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altough your example isn't reproducible, I get a list of lists with the following similar code:

```
potential_dups <- rep(list(list()), 10)
nearest10 <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10)
for (i in 1:10) {
  for (j in 1:10) {
    if (nearest10[i, j] < 0.35 & nearest10[i, j] > 0) {
      potential_dups[[i]] <- append(potential_dups[[i]], nearest10[i, j])
    }
  } 
}
```

To remove empty lists you can do this:

```
potential_dups[sapply(potential_dups, function(x) length(x) > 0)]
```

Comment: This is identical to my code. Doesn't this produce a lists of lists of lists?

Comment: No it produces a list of lists.

Comment: @user2568961 This answers my second question with your use of the sapply function. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nicer (better readable and more efficient) way:

```
mat <- nearest10
mat[mat >= 0.35 | mat <= 0] <- NA
potential_dups <- apply(mat,1,function(x) as.list(na.omit(x)))
```

However, I can't imagine why you want this output. It doesn't seem the most useful. maybe you could use the following instead?

```
potential_dups <- apply(mat,1,function(x) c(na.omit(x)))
```